# Resolution keeps defaulting to something else

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, monitor, display-resolution

I have a 27" 4K monitor, a GeForce GTX 950, and Ubuntu 16.04. I change my resolution and refresh rate to the correct value with this command:

`xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 3840x2160 --rate 60.00`

Unfortunately every time my monitor goes to sleep or I reboot, it defaults back to a lower resolution and I have to input the command again. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers? Which version?

Comment: The proprietary drivers, whichever version that is currently up to date in Xenial.